# React StrictMode causing state to be updated twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

// Is React.StrictMode is supposed to run the code twice updating any state twice initially. If not so then why am I having such a problem?

// index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

// App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setArr((prev) => [...prev, 1]);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {arr.map((value) => {
                return <p>{value}</p>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

// Expected output in console: [1]

// but getting: [1,1]

// THIS MEANS THAT STRICT MODE IS UPDATING arr FROM []->[1]->[1,1], BUT IT SHOULD ONLY RUN ONCE AT INITIAL RENDER. AND WHEN I RUN WITHOUT THE StrictMode IT GIVES ONLY [1] AS OUTPUT, WHICH IS THE EXPECTED OUTPUT.

Comment: This is well documented. https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development Your effect is impure.

Comment: But how do I make it pure, I can't understand. Please can u confirm by correcting the above? Because I am new to react and having difficulty in understanding this pure effect thing

Comment: I suspect your code is toy code to prove the double render and not something designed to actually do something you need (I think?)? To answer that question, we'd need to know what you are trying to achieve. What is your use case?

Comment: const getAllPokemons = async() => {
          const pokemonList = await fetchResults(
            url + `?offset=${offset}&limit=${pageSize}`
          );
          setPokemons((prevPokemons) => [...prevPokemons, ...pokemonList]);
  };

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  getAllPokemons();
}, [offset]);                                                                                                                        //offset state updated when scroll reaches bottom of the page to perform infinite scrolling